# Setup vhost for subdomain

Tags: php, apache-httpd, vhost

I am trying to make vhost, but it is kinda semi working. I am able to run the **index.php** and load home page, but when I try to go to any link I am getting:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /home was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at c2s.dev Port 80
```

(I am using **yii2** framework, if that means something). I also can access the site using subdomain (I am getting Server not found). What is the proper configuration? 
I am using Linux Mint 17.1 with default **LAMP** settings. This is my c2s.conf:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.1.1:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/c2c/www
  ServerName c2s.dev
  ServerAlias *.c2s.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

And in /etc/hosts I added this:

```
127.0.1.1   c2s.dev
127.0.1.1   *.c2s.dev
```

Answer (score 0):

The official site of Yii explains how to configure vhost for apache. You can see the examples [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#configuring-web-servers)

For apache basically the configuration is:

```
<Directory "path/to/basic/web">
    # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
    RewriteEngine on
    # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php

    # ...other settings...
</Directory>
```

For you case it could look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName c2s.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/c2c/www
    <Directory /var/www/c2c/www>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the file .htaccess on the root web folder like this:
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    IndexIgnore */*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    #RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
</IfModule>
```